# How can you prevent excess line breaks when pasting into any text editor and Chrome/IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a form to copy and paste as it looks but it adds multiple line breaks when pasting into a text editor and more importantly, into outlook.

Ex. HTML

```
<form id="TLM">
  <h1>Loan Modification Template</h1>
  <p>Date Submitted: <input type="text"/><br>
    Client Name: <input type="text"/><br>
    Account Number: <input type="text"/>
  </p>
</form>
```

Now, I want it to paste like this:

Date Submitted: 08/18/2017
Client Name: blah blah
Account Number: 739842

but what it always comes out as is:

Date Submitted:
08/18/2017
Client Name:
blah blah
Account Number:
739842

Is there any way to fix this or change it? When I take out the < br >'s from the HTML code, it completely changes the layout. Anyone have tips? I seriously have been looking for an answer and experimenting with any info I can find but nothing is working the way I need it to.

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**
Fixed width font did not resolve any issue and table only got rid of extra line break in between.

Ex.
Date Submitted:
08/18/2017
Client Name:
blah blah
Account Number:
739842

Combining both ideas had no extra effect.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it does look like text label and input field should display in the same line.

Check if there's any code at some other place, controlling features like para width, etc.

You may try below alternatives to see if that resolves the issue.

**Alternative 1** - use a fixed-width font, e.g. `Consolas`:

```
<h1>Loan Modification Template</h1>
<form id="TLM" style="font-family: Consolas;">
  <p>Date Submitted: <input type="text"/><br/>
    Client Name&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp: <input type="text"/><br/>
    Account Number: <input type="text"/>
  </p>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Alternative 2** - use a `table`:

```
<h1>Loan Modification Template</h1>
<form id="TLM">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Date Submitted:</th><th><input type="text"/></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Client Name</th><th><input type="text"/></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Number:</th><th><input type="text"/></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the first and changed the font and nothing changed at all. I tried the table idea and it did take away the extra breaks in between which, unfortunately, isn't my main issue :( 
Thank you for at least looking! If you need any other code or anything else, or have any other ideas, please let me know!

Comment: good to know that 2nd alternative worked. unless i see the whole html file, it's difficult to tell what's causing the undesirable line breaks